# how do i remove the dash symbol in a list, only if it's at the end of a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```py
coins = ['big-coin-','coins','bitcoin']

for coin in coins:
    if coin.endswith('-'):
        coin = coin.replace('-','')
        print(coin)

    print(coins)
```

replace isn't working? i want big-coin- to replace with big-coin. Thank you!

Comment: everyone answered this question so fast I'm not sure who to give the checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable. When you do `coin = coin.replace()`, the original `coin` isn't modified. Instead, you get a new string that is the result of `coin.replace()` stored with the name `coin`. If you don't write this `coin` to your list, it won't be in your list.

What you need to do is:

```
for coin, index in enumerate(coins):
    if coin.endswith('-'):
        coin = coin.replace('-', '')
        coins[index] = coin

print(coins)
```

Or you could get rid of the `if` statement if you do

```
for coin, index in enumerate(coins):
    coin = coin.rstrip('-')
    coins[index] = coin

print(coins)
```

As you've seen from Vishal's answer, this loop can be shortened to a list comprehension

```
coins = [coin.rstrip('-') for coin in coins]
```

Comment: "Strings are immutable. When you do coin = coin.replace(), the original coin isn't modified."  GOT IT.  thanks, you're getting a checkmark

Answer (score 1):

this uses a list comprehension to create a new list by removing **all** trailing `-` from every string present in the old list.

```
coins = [coin.rstrip('-') for coin in coins]
```

Comment: Code-only comments don't help OP or people looking at the answer in the future. It is often more helpful to know _why_ something needs to be done a particular way than to know that it needs to be done that way.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I hope the explanation suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace will remove the first "-" it finds. But since you already know the last character is a dash:

```
if coin.endswith("-"):
   coin = coin[:-1]
```

Or you think there may be more than one trailing dash to remove:

```
while coin.endswith("-"):
    coin = coin[:-1]
```

Edit: note `coin = coin[:-1]` will NOT change `coins`. You will need to either crate a new list or to fix the list you have in place:

```
for i in range(len(coins)]:
    coin[i] = coin[i][:-1]
```

Comment: Looking at your code again, I think you want to go with Vishal's answer since changing coin the way I showed will NOT change the element in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Replace working as expected replacing all '-' symbols to empty one. If you need to replace only ending one you should use the following code:

```
if coin.endswith('-'):
    coin = coin[:-1]
```

If you need inplace replacement without list comprehension, you should do it like following:

```
coins = ['big-coin-','coins','bitcoin']

for i in range(len(coins)):
    if coins[i].endswith('-'):
        coins[i] = coins[i][:-1]

print(coins)
```

But the best solution is use list comprehension

```
coins = ['big-coin-','coins','bitcoin']

coins = [coin[:-1] if coin.endswith('-') else coin for coin in coins]

print(coins)
```